# Is it possible to change the look of the Web Service interface in SSRS?

Tags: html, css, sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am wondering if it is possible to change the look of the ssrs web portal that users use to open and view reports? Are there any html or css files that i can possibly edit? I've tried to google this information but it is very unclear.

Here is a screenshot of a default view of the report server web service portal.
(sorry dont have the reputation to post direct images)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXILk.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your users should not be accessing reports through the web service url! Use the report manager, and you get control of permissions. It will be something like this: http://[servername]/Reports

Depending on the version of SQL Server you have installed you may still be disappointed. Anything prior to 2016 uses a very old front end. 2016 though, bring it up to modern HTML5 standards

Comment: Ok so i dont want users to use the web service url? Why not just curious? I guess that makes sense since its really not appealing. Is there a way to add customization to the report manager then? Add things such as logos?

Comment: Because you won't be able make full use of the features in the report manager web interface. As for customization; as I said that very much depends on the version of SQL Server you have installed. If 2016 yes, you can apply branding (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/03/20/how-to-create-a-custom-brand-package-for-reporting-services-with-sql-server-2016/). Anything earlier and you're stuck with the out-of-the-box experience.

Comment: Thanks! so much for the insight.